# How can I play a single video in a flatlist using this package react-native-video-player

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-flatlist

I'm trying to play a single video within a FlatList using the react-native-video-player package in my React Native application. However, I'm facing some difficulties with the implementation. Here's an overview of what I'm trying to achieve:
I have a FlatList component that displays multiple videos, and I want to enable the user to play a video by tapping on it. I'm using the react-native-video-player package to handle the video playback.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
`<VideoPlayer
    endWithThumbnail={true}
    fullScreenOnLongPress={true}
    paused={props.isPlay}
    onPlayPress={props.onPlayPress1}
    pauseOnPress={props.pauseOnPress1}
    autoplay={false}
    resizeMode="contain"
    video={{uri: props.filePath + item.name.replace(/ /g, '%20')}}
    style={styles.backgroundVideo}
    disableControlsAutoHide={true}
    thumbnail={{uri: props.filePath + item.thumbnail}}
/>

<FlatList
    data={props.inactiveLandings}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    renderItem={renderItemOtherInnovations}
/>

const onPlayPress1 = () => {
    setPlayData(false);
};

const pauseOnPress1 = () => {
    setPlayData(true);
};

const [isPlay, setPlay] = React.useState(false);

const setPlayData = value => {
    setPlay(value);
};`
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I tap on a video in the FlatList, all the videos start playing simultaneously, instead of playing just the selected video. I want to ensure that only the video associated with the tapped item is played.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all video components in your flatlist is listening to them same state `isPlay`.
To fix this, you should add an id to differentiate which video should play in your state like:

```
[playId, setPlayId] = useState('');

<VideoPlayer 
  paused={playId === id}
/>
```

But a better approach I think is you should handle play/pause inside your video component to prevent affecting to others video.